# In Avro why must we specify a "null" string for correct Enum types?

Tags: avro, avro-tools

I am completely new to Avro serialization and I am trying to get my head around how complex types are defined.

I am puzzled by how Avro generates the Enums in Java.

```
{
    "type":"record",
    "namespace":"com.example",
    "name": "Customer",
    "doc":"Avro Schema for our Customer",
    "fields":[
      {"name":"first_name","type":"string","doc":"First Name of Customer"},
      {"name":"last_name","type":"string","doc":"Last Name of Customer"},
      {"name":"automated_email","type":"boolean","doc":"true if the user wants marketing email", "default":true},
      {
        "name": "customer_type",
        "type": ["null",
          {
            "name": "Customertype",
            "type": "enum",
            "symbols": ["OLD","NEW"]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Notice the `customer_type` field. If I give `null`, then in my generated sources I get the correct `Enum` type which is :

```
private com.example.Customertype customer_type;
```

But the moment I remove the `null` value and define `customer_type` in the following way:

```
{
        "name": "customer_type",
        "type": [
          {
            "name": "Customertype",
            "type": "enum",
            "symbols": ["OLD","NEW"]
          }
        ]
      }
```

The declaration changes to :

```
private Object customer_type;
```

**What does that "null" string signify ? Why is it important ?**

I have tried looking through the AVRO specification but nothing has given me a clear cut answer **why this is working the way it is.**

I am using the **AVRO Maven plugin.**

Any beginner resources for AVRO will also be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to remove the `null`, you should remove the `[` and `]` brackets (because it is no longer a union).

So your `customer_type` schema should look like this:

```
{
        "name": "customer_type",
        "type": {
          "name": "Customertype",
          "type": "enum",
          "symbols": ["OLD","NEW"]
        }
      }
```

Comment: Yes but why does removing the `null` cause the type in the generated object to be `java.lang.Object` ?